# C# Azure Setup second ServiceBus for failover

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I tried to follow the steps mentioned from [Microsoft documentation to set up second ServiceBus to prevent ServiceBus outage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-async-messaging).

However, when I run below code, pairing never finishes:

```
public class ServiceBusContext
{
    public ServiceBusContext()
    {
        var nsManager1 = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString("...");
        var messageFactory1 = MessagingFactory.Create(nsManager1.Address, nsManager1.Settings.TokenProvider);

        var nsManager2 = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString("...");
        var messageFactory2 = MessagingFactory.Create(nsManager2.Address, nsManager2.Settings.TokenProvider);

        var sendAvailabilityOptions = new SendAvailabilityPairedNamespaceOptions(nsManager2, messageFactory2, 10, TimeSpan.Zero, false);

        messageFactory1.PairNamespaceAsync(sendAvailabilityOptions).Wait();

        Debug.WriteLine("Cannot reach this code");
    }
}
```

How to setup ServiceBuses with failover feature properly?

Comment: When your primary namespace  fail then it will go to secondary namespace that you configured. You could refer to this [article](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/service-bus-ha-with-paired-namespaces) which explain detailed.

Comment: Funny how the collective power of internet is outperforming individual's capabilities. I have forgotten about my own post  Thank you @JoeyCai for bringing it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this feature is still available with the old client, I would discourage from using it. Besides a few problematic design issues with the feature, it also doesn't really help with a flow where you need to send *and* receive. It is only designed for send-only scenario, leveraging fail-over (secondary) namespace as **storage**. Which inflates the cost in turn as well.

Not to mention that this is a legacy library. The contemporary equivalent is .NET Standard [`Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/) library. Instead, it offers [Geo-DR feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-geo-dr) (Premium only) which is not quite the same, but offers fail-over is trully critical scenarios where your namespace is gone. For other than that, the namespace should be available 24/7. With the additional support for [Availability Zones](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/blog/azure-service-bus-is-now-offering-support-for-availability-zones-in-preview/) with Service Bus (Premium only), you're getting

> financially-backed SLA with fault-isolated locations within an Azure region, providing redundant power, cooling, and networking.

which should remove the need for paired namespaces.

Comment: Some regions (Australia) do not have Geo-DR available